# How to show an element, using JS, before the page appears, after a refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to show "Field2"(dropdown) if "Field1"(Dropdown) has a value of "Yes", otherwise keep "Field2" hidden. This works fine, unless I refresh the page which does the following:

1) Load Page

2) Check for "Yes" in "Field1" and if so display "Field2", resulting in a "shudder" effect as "Field2" "shows" after the page has loaded. It would be better if this step was performed before the page load occurred.

Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($("#Field1").val()=="Yes") {
        //show the hidden div
        $("#Field2").show("fast");
    }
    else {
        //otherwise, hide it
        $("#Field2").hide("fast");
    }        
    $("#Field1").change(function () {
        // If checked
        if ($("#Field1").val() == "Yes") {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#Field2").show("fast");
        }
        else {
            //otherwise, hide it
            $("#Field2").hide("fast");
            $("#Field1").val("");
        }

    });


});
</script>
```

The above code works fine if the page is not refreshed. So how can I "show" Field2 prior to the page loading, to remove this "shudder" effect?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Got to a silution inspired by Cerbrus's answer.

Basically I hid the surrounding DIV using "display:none" and then "showed" it once the JS logic had processed. However the key bit was to include:

```
 setTimeout(function () { $("#WrapperDiv").show(); }, 20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option would be to use CSS to set both fields to hidden, and *then* show one of them based on the value of `#Field1`.

Something like this:

```js
alert("Simulating page load");
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#Field2").show(); // Your logic to choose the correct field, here.
}, 2000);
```

```css
input.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Field1" value="Field 1" class="hidden"/>
<br />
<input type="text" id="Field2" value="Field 2" class="hidden"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Are you using a timeout to mask the delay involved in processing the logic for Field2, and showing it if required? The server code is delayed enough without adding extra delays.

Comment: I added the delay to simulate a page load, to show that the elements only become visible after load.

Comment: ok. I may be misunderstanding something. "Field1" always stays visible. "Field2" is the conditional field. However I need this logic processing predisplay of the page so I get all 2 fields or 1 field, not "Field1" followed by "Field2". Is there some "onload" or "onloadstart" event that could be used to invoke a function to process this visibility.

Comment: Downvote, nothing to do with me. I did spot that...... Sadly I cannot correct the situation.

Comment: I got to a solution, and your answer helped me so I have marked it as the answer. See EDIT in my question. Thanks again for your help.